# ImageView not displaying image on phone

Tags: android

Hello there I am new to programming in general, but have slowly been teaching myself.

I am currently making a very basic program that mainly uses buttons (which all work perfectly).
However Now I want to add a pricelist so I added a button like usual that takes me to the pricelist activity. (normal boring stuff all working fine). I added the pricelist (imageview) onto the page. I use photoshop to change the resolution of the pictures and i set it to 1020*1900 (I have tried making it 900*1800). Everything works perfectly on the emulator and I can see the pricelist but when I switch to my android s4 it does not show the image. The emulator i use is the small nexus default one.

I set the layout height and widths to DP instead cause I heard that might solve the problem (didnt) and I added the contentDescription line (not sure what that does) because android studio was asking me to.

I appreciate all the help I can get! thanks.

Complete Code for the activity. The buttons are just basic buttons that I keep on all my activities in order to take them back to the respective main menus.

?xml version="1.0" 
encoding="utf-8"?>

```
RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btn1"
    android:onClick="doSomething"
    android:id="@+id/machines"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/pl"
    android:id="@+id/pl"
    android:onClick="doSomething3"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btn2"
    android:id="@+id/spares"
    android:onClick="doSomething2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/machines"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/machines"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/pricelist1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I decided to add a linearlayout just for completeness, but I have tried it without it and it has made no difference. Perhaps could be something to do with the relativelayout?

Comment: can you please share your complete layout ?

Comment: anything interesting in logcat? Btw. the contentDescription should be a string describing the content of the image (for visually impaired people)

Comment: tbh I dont really know how to use logcat effectively. Always so much stuff to look at

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/machines"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:onClick="doSomething"
    android:text="@string/btn1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/pl"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="doSomething3" 
    android:text="@string/pl"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/spares"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:onClick="doSomething2"
    android:text="@string/btn2" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/machines"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/pricelist1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: rather add an explanation what you did instead of just posting a code block. It might prove useful in helping others understand more clearly what went wrong and what you did to solve it :)

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your xml on s4 emulator and its working fine in my emulator. By making just one or two changes.

you can test this xml that I am posting. I have made few changes related to string and image, you can change as per yours.

Note: Image i have used for testing is of size 1020x1900 px.

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<Button
    android:id="@+id/machines"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:onClick="doSomething"
    android:text="b1" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/pl"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="doSomething3"
    android:text="b2_p1" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/spares"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:onClick="doSomething2"
    android:text="btn2" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/machines"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/machines"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/machines"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/test2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Try this and let me is it working or not...

Comment: could you explain what changes you made please?

Comment: also my code does work on my emulator but it does not work when I use my cellphone.

Comment: Nothing much actually i dont have text and image that you are using  in your xml thats why i have changed that to remove error in my xml you can change it later. You can directly use the xml that i have posted.

Comment: i have tested this xml on my s4 emulator(genymotion).. Which reflects same as you are debugging anything on real device. So, it should work on your real device too.